# swiftui widget button intent has a default background, how to remove it

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget, ios17

I'm build a widget for a iOS17 app, and below is widget' button code

```
var body: some View {

    if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
        Button(intent: TodoCheckInIntent(todoId: todo.id)) {
            Text("hello")
        }
        .frame(width: 65, height: 21)
    } else {
        todoSubView
    }
}
```

After run on ios17, it's like this. The button has a wired blue background.
My Question is how to remove the wired blue background.

[image: Demo]

Thanks for any answer

I have use `.padding(0)` to the Button, but don't have any effects

Comment: Have you tried setting the button style to plain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because of the default button style. You should use `.buttonStyle(.plain)` on the button:

```
Button(intent: TodoCheckInIntent(todoId: todo.id)) {
    Text("hello")
}
.frame(width: 65, height: 21)
.buttonStyle(.plain) //  Here
```

Comment: it works, Thank you very much!